# Rename function doesn't work, using c++

Tags: c++

This is the code snippet which i had written:

I am using **turbo c++** (because I'm studying in India); **my problem is written in a comment**.

```
void Sort()
    {
        ofstream Change("temp.dat",ios::binary);
        ifstream RData("Student.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);
        Student S[1000];
        int q=0;
        while(RData.read((char*)&S[q],sizeof(Student)))
            q++;
        int w=0;
        Student temp;
        for(int e=0;e<q-w;++e)
            for(w=0;w+1<q;++w)
                if(strcmp(S[w+1].accnm(),S[w].accnm())<0)
                {
                    temp=S[w+1];
                    S[w+1]=S[w];
                    S[w]=temp;
                }
        w=0;
        while(!Change.eof()&&w<q)
        {
            Change.write((char*)&S[w],sizeof(Student));
            w++;
        }
        cout<<"\nSorted";
        cout<<"\nWould you like to add a record to the sorted records\nsuch that the records remain sorted?(y/n)(case sensitive)\n";
        if(getche()=='y')
        {
            e=0;
            Change.seekp(0);
            if(q==999){cout<<"No more records can be added .You can rewrite records by the insert option in menu.";return;}
            temp.insdata();
            for(w=0;w<q;w++)
                if(strcmp(S[w].accnm(),temp.accnm())<0&&!e)
                    Change.write((char*)&S[w],sizeof(Student));
                else
                {
                    Change.write((char*)&temp,sizeof(Student));
                    Change.write((char*)&S[w],sizeof(Student));
                    e=1;
                }
        }
        remove("Student.dat");
        rename("temp.dat","Student.dat");//doesn't rename
        Change.close();
        RData.close();
    }
```

No error shown by compiler but it doesn't rename the file but it removes the file

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic, but if you can, you should try and talk to whoever manages what compiler you use about upgrading. Turbo C++ is at this point 8 years old and horrifically out of date, you're being locked out of the ability to use the full features of modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to close temp file before rename it:

```
Change.close();
```

Also, try to take a look at [rename documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/) and check rename return result.

```
result= rename( oldname , newname );
if ( result == 0 ) {
   // File successfully renamed" 
} else {
   // "Error renaming file" 
}
```

Comment: please add this as comment if you are not sure about the answer or you are suggesting something

Comment: Thanks but why does it need to be closed before using rename and remove exactly what happens?